# json.getJSONArray() throwing exception with one length one

Tags: android, json, rest

I am having android with converts the JSON string to its original java object.

I am returning the List from REST server and it converts List into JSON format like this.

```
{"offerRideResult":[{"date":"06-APR-13 10.00.00.000000 AM","destination":"B","id":"57","PTripId":"87","req":"false","source":"A","srNo":"0","username":"Chinmay"},{"date":"06-APR-13 10.00.00.000000 AM","destination":"B","id":"1","PTripId":"88","req":"false","source":"A","srNo":"0","username":"chinmay91"}]}
```

On the client side that is android I am using the following method to convert it into java object.

```
    try{
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray arr=null;
            arr=obj.getJSONArray("offerRideResult");
            List<OfferRideResult> offerRideResult=new ArrayList<OfferRideResult>();
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
            {
                OfferRideResult res=new OfferRideResult();
                res.setId(arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
                res.setPTripId(arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("PTripId"));
                res.setSrNo(arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("srNo"));
                res.setDate(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"));
                res.setSource(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("source"));
                res.setDestination(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("destination"));
                res.setReq(arr.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("req"));
                res.setUsername(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("username"));
                offerRideResult.add(res);
            }
    }catch(JSONException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception :- "+e);
            }
```

It works fine when JSON format has two or more than two records but with on record it throws  the following exception when input is like this.

```
{"offerRideResult":{"date":"05-APR-13 10.00.00.000000 AM","destination":"B","id":"1","PTripId":"89","req":"false","source":"A","srNo":"0","username":"chinmay91"}}

Error!!!org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["offerRideResult"] is not a JSONArray
```

Can anybody please point my mistake or how can I deal with array of length one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but with on record it throws the following exception

use [JSONObject.optJSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29) or [JSONObject.optJSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29) for extracting next item from main `JSONObject`.try it as:

```
 JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);
 JSONArray arr=null;
 JSONObject jsonobj=null;

 // get offerRideResult JSONArray
 arr=obj.optJSONArray("offerRideResult");

 if(arr==null){
  // means item is JSONObject instead of JSONArray
 jsonobj=obj.optJSONObject("offerRideResult");
 }else{
  // means item is JSONArray instead of JSONObject
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the json with only one results is not an array it's not going to be read correctly by getJSONArray()

either you can make your json string more like:

```
{"offerRideResult":[{"date":"05-APR-13 10.00.00.000000 AM","destination":"B","id":"1","PTripId":"89","req":"false","source":"A","srNo":"0","username":"chinmay91"}]}
```

or read it in as a single object like @ρяσѕρєя K proposes.

Comment: I wish I could do that but I am simply returning the List from REST and so I cannot modify it... But thanks for your pointing my mistake that with one record there was no [ ]...